# Scraped Table Won't Print in Full

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am scraping a table from a website and I have not had any problems getting the data, but I am having issues printing the final output. In the code I've provided it prints everything, no issues if it prints within my 'for' statement (see the commented out print commands). However if I print it later in the code, outside of the 'for' statement, I only get the first row. I'd like to take this code and put it in a larger project where this output (among others) are in a single email. How do I get the entire output to appear?

I've tried appending each table row to a list, I think I am doing it wrong, but it just prints the same row over and over or individual letters from the first row.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36'}

#print('Scraping Iowa Dept of Banking...')


url = 'https://www.idob.state.ia.us/bank/docs/applica/app_status.aspx'
r = requests.get(url, headers = headers)


soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')


mylist = []
for tr in soup.find_all('tr')[2:]:
    tds = tr.find_all('td')
    if len(tds[5].text) == 1:
        edate = "NA"
    else:
        edate = ""
    if len(tds[6].text) == 1:
        loc = "NA"
    else:
        loc = ""
    output5 = ("Bank: %s, City: %s, Type: %s, Effective Date: %s, Location: %s, Comment: %s \r\n" % (tds[0].text, tds[1].text, tds[2].text.replace(" ", ""), tds[5].text+edate, tds[6].text.replace(" ", "")+loc, tds[7].text))


    global outputs5
    outputs5 = output5
    #print(outputs5) #The whole table prints if printed here

if outputs5 is None:
    outputs5 = "No information available"
    print(outputs5)

print(outputs5) #only prints the first line
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this, you need to append the outputs to the list and then join the list together before printing it.

The reason why your print inside the loop worked was because it actually printed 5 times, not just once.

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36'}

#print('Scraping Iowa Dept of Banking...')

url = 'https://www.idob.state.ia.us/bank/docs/applica/app_status.aspx'
r = requests.get(url, headers = headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

mylist = []
for tr in soup.find_all('tr')[2:]:
    tds = tr.find_all('td')
    if len(tds[5].text) == 1:
        edate = "NA"
    else:
        edate = ""
    if len(tds[6].text) == 1:
        loc = "NA"
    else:
        loc = ""
    output5 = ("Bank: %s, City: %s, Type: %s, Effective Date: %s, Location: %s, Comment: %s \r\n" % (tds[0].text, tds[1].text, tds[2].text.replace(" ", ""), tds[5].text+edate, tds[6].text.replace(" ", "")+loc, tds[7].text))

    mylist.append(outputs5)

if mylist == []:
    print("No information available")

print('\n'.join(mylist))
```

Answer (score 3):

I would love to use pandas which is python library and extract the table and import into csv.

```
import pandas as pd
tables=pd.read_html("https://www.idob.state.ia.us/bank/docs/applica/app_status.aspx")
tables[1].to_csv('output.csv')
```

Csv will look like that.

[image]

It is so easy to install pandas.Just type in command prompt.

> pip install pandas

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using pandas' `.read_html()`?

```
import pandas as pd

url ='https://www.idob.state.ia.us/bank/docs/applica/app_status.aspx'

tables = pd.read_html(url)
```

**Output:**

```
print (tables[-1].to_string())
                                     Bank             City                                        Type    Accepted    Approved Effective #      Location                                            Comment
0                              State Bank      New Hampton                         Merge With and Into  05/21/2019         NaN         NaN           NaN  Application to merge State Bank, New Hampton, ...
1        Farmers and Traders Savings Bank            Douds                         Merge With and Into  05/20/2019         NaN         NaN           NaN  Application to merge Farmers and Traders Savin...
2                         City State Bank          Norwalk                     Establish a Bank Office  05/15/2019  05/29/2019         NaN      Mesa, AZ  Application by City State Bank, Norwalk, to es...
3                             Availa Bank          Carroll                     Purchase and Assumption  04/16/2019  04/30/2019         NaN           NaN  Application by Availa Bank, Carroll, to purcha...
4                               West Bank  West Des Moines                     Establish a Bank Office  04/16/2019  05/02/2019  05/10/2019   Mankato, MN  Application by West Bank, West Des Moines, to ...
5                               West Bank  West Des Moines                     Establish a Bank Office  04/10/2019  05/02/2019  05/07/2019  Owatonna, MN  Application by West Bank, West Des Moines, to ...
6                               West Bank  West Des Moines                     Establish a Bank Office  04/09/2019  05/02/2019  05/07/2019           NaN  Application by West Bank, West Des Moines, to ...
7                         Iowa State Bank           Algona                     Establish a Bank Office  03/15/2019         NaN         NaN   Phoenix, AZ  Application by Iowa State Bank, Algona, to est...
8                    Peoples Savings Bank             Elma                         Merge With and Into  03/13/2019  04/24/2019         NaN           NaN  Application to merge Peoples State Bank, Elma,...
9                 Two Rivers Bank & Trust       Burlington                     Purchase and Assumption  01/25/2019  01/31/2019  05/31/2019           NaN  Application by Two Rivers Bank & Trust, Burlin...
10                    Westside State Bank         Westside                     Establish a Bank Office  01/25/2019  02/06/2019         NaN  Bellevue, NE  Application by Westside State Bank, Westside, ...
11                         Northwest Bank          Spencer                      Relocate a Bank Office  11/29/2018  12/12/2018         NaN        Ankeny  Application by Northwest Bank, Spencer, to rel...
12                        City State Bank          Norwalk                     Establish a Bank Office  11/21/2018  12/12/2018         NaN       Norwalk  Application by City State Bank, Norwalk, to es...
13  First Security Bank and Trust Company     Charles City                      Relocate a Bank Office  06/21/2018  06/29/2018         NaN         Manly  Application by First Security Bank and Trust C...
14                   Lincoln Savings Bank      Cedar Falls                     Establish a Bank Office  06/04/2018  06/25/2018         NaN    Des Moines  Application by Lincoln Savings Bank, Cedar Fal...
15                    Raccoon Valley Bank            Perry                     Establish a Bank Office  02/12/2018  03/02/2018         NaN        Grimes  Application by Raccoon Valley Bank, Perry, to ...
16                 Community Savings Bank         Edgewood                      Relocate a Bank Office  01/25/2018  01/25/2018         NaN    Manchester  Application by Community Savings Bank, Edgewoo...
17                     Luana Savings Bank            Luana                     Establish a Bank Office  06/05/2017  08/16/2017         NaN       Norwalk  Application by Luana Savings Bank, Luana, to e...
18         Fort Madison Financial Company     Fort Madison                         Change of Ownership         NaN  10/19/2017         NaN           NaN  Application for Linda Sue Baier, Fort Madison,...
19                        Lincoln Bancorp         Reinbeck                         Change of Ownership         NaN  12/10/2018         NaN           NaN  Application for Lincoln Bancorp Employee Stock...
20           Emmetsburg Bank Shares, Inc.       Emmetsburg                         Change of Ownership         NaN  01/17/2019         NaN           NaN  Application for Charles and Maryanna Sarazine,...
21      Albrecht Financial Services, Inc.          Norwalk                           Change of Control         NaN  03/27/2019  05/10/2019           NaN  Application for Dean L. Albrecht 2014 Family T...
22                  Solon Financial, Inc.            Solon                         Change of Ownership         NaN  03/05/2019         NaN           NaN  Application for Cordelia A. Cosgrove, Bruce A....
23                How-Win Development Co.           Cresco                         Change of Ownership         NaN  03/28/2019         NaN           NaN  Application for John Scott Thomson, as trustee...
24                      Lee Capital Corp.     Fort Madison                         Change of Ownership         NaN  04/15/2019         NaN           NaN  Application by Jean M. Humphrey, Kathleen A. M...
25                    FNB BanShares, Inc.       West Union                         Change of Ownership         NaN  05/02/2019         NaN           NaN  Application for James L. Moss, individually an...
26          Old O'Brien Banc Shares, Inc.       Sutherland                         Change of Ownership         NaN  03/06/2019         NaN           NaN  Application for James J. Johnson and Colleen D...
27            Pella Financial Group, Inc.            Pella                           Change of Control         NaN  03/15/2019         NaN           NaN  Application for Pella Financial Group, Inc., P...
28                                   BANK          Wapello  Amend or Restate Articles of Incorporation         NaN  05/07/2019  05/07/2019           NaN          Restatement of Articles of Incorporation.
29                  Security Agency, Inc.          Decorah                         Change of Ownership         NaN  11/28/2018         NaN           NaN  Application for the 2018 Grantor Trust FBO Rac...
30                          Arendt's Inc.        Montezuma                         Change of Ownership         NaN  05/29/2019         NaN           NaN  Application for C. W. Bolen, Montezuma, indivi...
```